# 301 Redirect entire site to new site using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

Ive got a site `siteONE.co.uk` that i want to 301 permanent redirect all the pages to another site, `siteTWO.co.uk`

For this im currently using the this `.htaccess` file below, but im have to type out a new line for each page i want to rediect even though they are all going to the homepage of `siteTWO.co.uk`. They are also redirecting incorrectly, instead of `siteONE.co.uk/aberdeen` going to `siteTWO.co.uk` its going to `siteTWO.co.ukaberdeen` (note there is not `/` between the .co.uk and aberdeen)

Any ideas were im going wrong with this ?

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(http://siteONE\.co\.uk)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.siteONE.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
order deny,allow


RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://siteTWO.co.uk/ [R=301,L]

redirect 301 / http://siteTWO.co.uk
redirect 301 /aberdeen http://siteTWO.co.uk
redirect 301 /bath http://siteTWO.co.uk
redirect 301 /belfast http://siteTWO.co.uk
redirect 301 /birmingham http://siteTWO.co.uk
redirect 301 /cambridge http://siteTWO.co.uk
redirect 301 /canterbury http://siteTWO.co.uk
redirect 301 /chester http://siteTWO.co.uk
redirect 301 /york http://siteTWO.co.uk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of all the code in your .htaccess and use this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^ http://siteTWO.co.uk/? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, but that takes all urls from siteONE to the equivilent url on siteTWO, is there a way to make all urls from siteONE go to the home page on siteTWO. ie. `http://siteONE.co.uk/mypage` would go to `http://siteTWO.co.uk` not `http://siteTWO.co.uk/mypage`  ?

Comment: Thanks @anubhava ! ive added in the top part of my original file (starting `<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">` and finishing `order deny,allow`) so that it redirects both `www.` and `non-www`. Then ive got your snippet. Ive uploaded it to the serve and it seems to work, is there any reason for my first snippet or would your snippet handle both tasks ? Also is the `k` from `.co.uk` replaced with a `?` or is that a typo ?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo (corrected now). This should work fine just below `order deny,allow` as you mentioned. This way you don't need to redirect page by page as you are doing and btw your first rule `redirect 301 / http://siteTWO.co.uk` would supersede all below rules.